# JIRA query to find all issues where acceptance criteria is less than 20 characters

Tags: jira, acceptance-criteria

can anyone help me with a JQL to filter all jira issues in my project that have acceptance criteria less than 20 characters

Comment: I think your agile is really broken if you need to do something like this.

Comment: This isn't really the right sub for this, it seems more of a technical issues with JIRA and contacting their support or other technology avenues would be more beneficial.

Specifically as it related to this community, talk to why you are interested in doing this, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Jira does not offer any native character count function. A few alternatives:

- Export to CSV and filter the data in Excel
- Use Jira API
- Use [ScriptRunner](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/jql-functions.html#_regular_expressions), as you can see [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/query-for-text-field-length/qaq-p/696968): `issueFunction in issueFieldMatch("project = FOO", "description", "^.{0,10}$")`

Now, more on the PM context: **People using such small acceptance criteria are either very *seasoned* or very *junior*.** Understand what's your case. Short acceptance criteria is a *sympton*, not a *sickness*. I'd avoid monitoring such criteria. Understand why such cases exist and deal with them. Do not consider any of the above approaches as something *sustainable in the long run*.